# Precision/units in OpenGL

Tags: xcode, cocoa, opengl, 3d

I am currently developing in OpenGL and use the meter as my own unit, i.e. 0.2 for a 20 cm wide triangle.
However OpenGL seems to round these figures, which ends in shapes not exactly following my wishes.
Is this normal in OpenGL, and should I use centimeters as the unit instead?

Comment: Can you post an example of the code you are using and the output you get?

Comment: It's posted here: http://www.petits-suisses.ch/openglPrecisionIssue.jpg

Comment: You see the issue on p4, which is supposed to be on the same y level than p5 but isn't. Removing 0.01 on p4 makes it do a jump to p5, but I would expect/need more precision. Thanks !

Comment: Ooops, it was a bug in my Polygon -> triangle conversion algorithm. Sorry !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to use 1m for 1 unit in GL space, the shape distortion might be caused the incorrect perspective, either too much twisted or flattened, or higher than usual. This is because of incorrect viewport ratio, etc.

OpenGL never rounds up anything, only the precision limit of float or double types.

If you are using OpenGL for architecture, I suggest considering 1 GL unit as 1mm.

Answer (score 1):

OpenGL units are simply units, measures of some unspecified thing. They can mean whatever you want. Unless you are getting incredibly small, large, or precise, it won't make a practical difference. 0.2 should be fine.